# How to make dropdown item a submit

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

My code below submit's perfectly as i want but the Add & Create new item in the bootstrap dropdown i need to be a submit, i've tried with javascript but then the html5 validation dosen't trigger. Is my only option to try and style the submit button like the bootstrap dropdown-item ?

```
    $('btnWorkorder_Add_Create').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#WorkOrderFrm').append('<input type="hidden" name="btnWorkorder_Add_Create" value="1">');
      $("#WorkOrderFrm").valid();
      $('#WorkOrderFrm').submit();
    });
```

HTML

```
    <form id="WorkOrderFrm" name="WorkOrderFrm" action="/proc/WorkOrderFrm.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

  <div class="btn-group">

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="submit" id="BtnAdd" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm" name="btnWorkorder_Add">Add</button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>

      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="" name="btnWorkorder_Add_Create" id="btnWorkorder_Add_Create">Add & Create New</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm... I don't see the form in your code example

Comment: Sorry its there now, the form is working with the standard button=submit

but i want to detect the Add & Create new and submit but with html5 validation working

Comment: Why don't you just write `<button type="submit" class="dropdown-item" name="btnWorkorder_Add_Create" id="btnWorkorder_Add_Create">Add & Create New</button>`?

Comment: Because it looks weird then in the dropdown, that's what i was going to use as a last resort

Comment: Actually i just tried it, I left the </button> off when i tested it... im an idiot thanks lumio for your help

Comment: No worries :) we've all been there!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you needing a dropdown if there is only one option?? Why not just use `<input type='submit' value='Add And Create New' />`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing '#' tag. try this code and let me know if it is still not working

```
   $('#btnWorkorder_Add_Create').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#WorkOrderFrm').append('<input type="hidden" name="btnWorkorder_Add_Create" value="1">');
      $("#WorkOrderFrm").valid();
      $('#WorkOrderFrm').submit();
    });
```